# Load part of JSON object to Datatable with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I have a page with a Datatable and I'm fetching data by loading a JSON object through AJAX. This works fine.
I want to add another Datatable and in order not to make an AJAX query to two different pages, I want to put all data into one JSON object and extract just one nested object for each Datatable. I simply can't get it to work.

First scenario that works fine:
I get this JSON string

```
{
    "data": [{ 
        "id": "8", 
        "organization_id": "1",
        "name": "Some name",
        "text": "Some text",
        "category": "0",
        "status": "0"
    }]
}
```

by loading

```
<script>
    var json_output_page_path = '<?php echo $json_output_page_path; ?>';
</script>
```

In my Datatable JS I access it like this

```
"ajax": json_output_page_path,
"columns": [
    { "data": "name" },
    { "data": "text" },
    { "data": "category" },
    { "data": "status" } 
],
```

If I nest the original PHP array for each object then I get this JSON object:

```
{
    "openprojects": {
        "data":[{
            "id": "8",
            "organization_id": "1",
            "name": "Some name",
            "text": "Some text",
            "category": "0",
            "status": "0"
        }]
    },
    "closedprojects": {
        "data": [{
            "id": "8",
            "organization_id": "1",
            "name": "Another name",
            "text":"Another text",
            "category":"0",
            "status":"0"
        }]
    }
}
```

I thought I could access the nested array with a "." notation but it doesn't fetch any data to the Datatable. I think it could have something to do with not being a JSON object before the Datatable loads it.
What is the solution to this?

Thanks. I really appreciate your help.

---

I solved it ... kind of :-)
I found the answer in these two links to the documentation.
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()

The solution to the problem is:

```
`$('#example').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data.json", //where this is the link to the JSON source relative to the page where the HTML table is on.
        "dataSrc": "tableData" //Where this is the reference to the nested object
    }
});`
```

The problem is still there though since the request is now made separately for each table.
Furthermore I found this answer but can you help me tell how that is done? 
"What I would suggest is that you make the Ajax call to get the data yourself using $.ajax() and then use the dataDT option, or rows.add()DT method, to add the data tot he tables."
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25309/reuse-ajax-source-for-multiple-tables-on-the-same-page

I don't know how that would be done. Can anyone specify or suggest another solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked using the name, like if the variable was `projects`, you could try `projects["openprojects"]`? What do you see on the console?

Comment: Yes, I tried for testing to output the object and the use the `data: json_output_page_path` as described below with you mentioned notation. I can't get it to work.

Comment: Could you host a workable part of the code on jsfiddle. It will be easier to debug. You don't need to post AJAX code, just assume the AJAX is resolved (or use echo service or something)

Comment: I posted a JSFiddle on this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3Ln1npj9/).

I was not quite sure how to set up the JSON call because I haven't Fiddled before. I hope it makes sense anyway.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

encode your php array using `var json = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>`
then in the `<script>` tag log this `console.log( json )` to see if you get the right object.

and make user you are assigned the right option to your datatable plugin

`data: json_output_page_path`  instated of `"ajax": json_output_page_path`

to access the new object you need to do this 
`json.openprojects.data` or `json["openprojects"]["data"]`

Comment: I have json encoded the string already and it outputs correctly. It also works correctly when I don't nest it.
In the console I get the path to the controller that outputs the JSON object. I don't get the actual object.
If this should be the case then how do I change that?